# How dump query to JSON in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have problem with dumping data to json, I use below code and I get exception on this line

```
Result = json.dumps([{'jalaliDate': o.jalaliDate} for o in matchDays], cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

MatchDays value is `[{'jalaliDate': u'1392/07/30'}]`

I think something is wrong with `values("jalaliDate")` in my filter cause when I remove it every thing is ok.

```
def calendar(request, year, month, day, hash):
    try:
        gregorianList = JalaliToGregorian(year, month, day).getGregorianList()
        startDate = datetime.date(gregorianList[0]-1,gregorianList[1],gregorianList[2])
        endDate = datetime.date(gregorianList[0]+1,gregorianList[1],gregorianList[2])
        matchDays = Match.objects.filter(matchDate__gt=startDate, matchDate__lt=endDate).values("jalaliDate").distinct()
        result = json.dumps([{'jalaliDate': o.jalaliDate} for o in matchDays], cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    except Exception:
        print Exception.message
    return result
```

This is response on console

```
0 errors found
October 23, 2013 - 16:18:04
Django version 1.5.2, using settings 'topelevensdjango.settings'
Development server is running at 127.0.0.1:800
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
<attribute 'message' of 'exceptions.BaseException' objects>
[23/Oct/2013 16:18:14] "POST /json/ HTTP/1.1" 500 723
```

This is response on web

```
>>> jsonrpc.calendar(1392, 1, 1, 22)
Requesting ->
{"id":"jsonrpc", "params":[1392, 1, 1, 22], "method":"calendar", "jsonrpc":"1.0"}
Deferred(128, unfired)
Error ->
STATUS: 500
[object Object]
```

Comment: i use pycharm doesn't shows exception only shows error 500

Comment: I think something is wrong with values in my filter cause when i remove it every thing is ok

Comment: Well, because you are printing `Exception.messages`, which doesn't exist - maybe you meant `Exception.message`?

Comment: Can you please provide a full traceback?

Comment: these are all I have got :(((

Comment: Is `Match` your own class?

Comment: yes Match is one of my models

Comment: You aren't printing the exception message; use `catch Exception as e: print e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have find the answer 
for grouping the result i used distinct that was wrong

i have replaced this code

```
matchDays = Match.objects.filter(matchDate__gt=startDate, matchDate__lt=endDate).values("jalaliDate").distinct()
```

with this code

```
matchDays = Match.objects.filter(matchDate__gt=startDate, matchDate__lt=endDate)
matchDays.query.group_by = ['jalaliDate']
```

and the problem is gone
bye